# Blocking Keyboard Play/Pause Button in Win 8

Tags: c++, hook, keyboard-hook, setwindowshookex

I am writing an application that needs to temporarily disable the Play/Pause button that appears on multimedia keyboards.

Normally, a key can be blocked quite easily by installing a low level keyboard hook (`WH_KEYBOARD_LL`) where the `KeyboardProc` intercepts the key (in this case `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE`) and returns 1 instead of calling `CallNextHookEx`. I have tried this with other keys (including the Windows key `VK_LWIN`) and this works perfectly. I also have no problems with this method under Windows 7 where all keys, including `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` get blocked.

Windows 8 is a different story.  When my application has input focus, everything works as expected, meaning the `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` key gets blocked and no other application responds to it.  However, when my application loses focus, my hook procedure gets called (this was verified by sending out a `OutputDebugString`) but other applications respond to key even though I return 1.  As soon as my app gets focus again, everything is block as it should.

After some investigation, I found that the multimedia keys not only generate keystrokes but also generate `WM_APPCOMMAND` messages so I added `ShellProc (WH_SHELL)` hook with the following hook procedure:

```
LRESULT __declspec(dllexport)__stdcall  CALLBACK ShellProc(int nCode,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
// Do we have to handle this message?
if (nCode == HSHELL_APPCOMMAND)
{
    OutputDebugStringX(">>>>>    HSHELL_APPCOMMAND");
    // Process the hook if the hNotifyWnd window handle is valid
        short AppCommand = GET_APPCOMMAND_LPARAM(lParam);
        switch (AppCommand)
        {
        case APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_NEXTTRACK:
        case APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
        case APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PREVIOUSTRACK:
        case APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_STOP:
            OutputDebugString(">>>>>ShellProc got a media command");
            return 1;

        }
}

// Call the next handler in the chain
return CallNextHookEx (hsh, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This procedure is only getting called when my app has input focus.  Whenever I have input focus and return 1 the Play/Pause command gets blocked.  As soon as I lose focus the procedure does not get called/hooked.

Anyone have any idea as to what is going on?  As I have mentioned, the code works for other keys, just not the multimedia keys. Everything works fine in Windows 7.

Alternatively, can anyone suggest another way of blocking the multimedia keyboards Play/Pause button?

Comment: Show us how you're setting up the hook.

Comment: To set up the hook I am calling: hsh=SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL,(HOOKPROC)ShellProc,hins,0); which returns successfully

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN documentation for [ShellProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> HSHELL_APPCOMMAND:  The user completed an input event (for example, pressed an application command button on the mouse or an application command key on the keyboard), and **the application did not handle the WM_APPCOMMAND message** generated by that input.  [Emphasis added.]

The emphasized portion suggests that your hook callback only gets called after an application ignores the WM_APPCOMMAND.  In other words, you're too late.

To catch the message in flight, I think you need a different type of hook.  Perhaps WH_GETMESSAGE or WH_CALLWNDPROC.

But why are you trying to prevent the users from interacting with their applications as they choose?

Comment: If that were the case (i.e. being too late) why am I able to hook and block the APPCOMMAND when my application is in the foreground?  
Also, even if the APPCOMMAND was only being called afterwards, why is my hook proc not being called at all when my application is not in the foreground?

Comment: Is your app the one setting the hook(s)?  Are you still setting both the WH_KEYBOARD_LL and the WH_SHELL?  Are they both attempting to block?  Is the other application the same bitness (32-/64-?) as yours?  Is the other application at the same integrity level as yours?  Depending on the answers to these questions, I can see lots of scenarios that are consistent with the observed behavior and my answer.

Comment: Is the other application a Windows Store app?  Looks like you may not be able to load global hooks into a store app (or from one).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: My 32-bit app is the one setting the hooks.  It is running elevated under the SYSTEM account with uiAccess.  The application that I am trying to block is a 32-bit application (MS Media Player) that is not elevated. Both are running in the same desktop - no store apps involved.  The OS is 64 bit Windows 8.1 Pro. I have both the WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_SHELL hooks set but at the moment I am returning CallNextHookEx for the KeyboardProc since it was not blocking the VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE when I returned 1 anyway.  Can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: Perhaps Media Player is also using a low-level keyboard hook which happens to be earlier in the hook chain than yours.  And are you sure the MS Media Player that comes with Windows 8.1 is _not_ a Windows Store app?  It's not clear to me that desktop apps are necessarily mutually exclusive with store apps.

Comment: To be honest I know nothing about Windows Store apps. I was under the impression that Windows Media player was solely a desktop app since by default Win 8 comes with a separate movie and separate video player that run as store apps.  I never thought it can be both.  Perhaps someone else knows the answer to that. I will investigate this.

Comment: You make a good point about the hooking order. That is also very mysterious to me.  I always thought the last hook that is set is the first to be called - I may be wrong about that.  It is interesting to note that the VLC media player, which is a very nicely written piece of software can only be controlled by the media keys when it has input focus.  Microsoft's Media Player is the only player I know that can be controlled with the keys regardless of input focus.  I can even be controlled while in the modern desktop. They obviously know something I (and the makers of VLC) do not.